# Высокоразвитый и недоразвитый

Tags: лексика

Есть слова высокорАзвитый и недорАзвитый. По аналогии с подвижным ударением второго корня этого сложного слова, можно ли образовать формы высокоразвитОй и недоразвитОй?

Comment: А кто вам, простите, сказал, что ударение "подвижное" ? У слова развит(0/ы)й три значения, различающихся ударением. Но оно постоянно для слофоформ каждого из этих значений.

Comment: Недоразвитой — невысокоразвитой?